# Runtime error 429: Active X component cannot create an object

Tags: vb.net, vb6

I am a newbie to vb6 and microsoft technologies. I am trying to run a vb6 application. When i open the app and try running the app, I get the following error in a dialog box "Runtime error 429: Active X component cannot create an object" and gives me two options "debug" and "end".
Environment: windows 8.1 64bit, vb6

When i click on end/debug it highlights the following code in yellow "Set m_oSNTPCtrl = CreateObject("SNTPWizard.SNTPWizardCtrl2")"..

What could be the error any missing DLL's/OCX files????

The class looks like this:

```
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
On Error GoTo ErrHndlr
Set m_oSNTPCtrl = CreateObject("SNTPWizard.SNTPWizardCtrl2")
m_oSNTPCtrl.UnlockSNTPWizard "SNTPWIZ-0200002100230152"
Exit Sub
ErrHndlr:
Call LogError(Err.Description, "Class_Initialize()")
End Sub
```

Comment: The CreateObject function only works if you have the DLL which is represented by the string inside of the CreateObject function registered on your workstation.  You should contact the party that you got this code from and see what dependencies are required to be installed on your machine prior to running the code.

Comment: the ActiveX library SNTPWizard is missing from your system, you have to install it first.

Comment: @milevyo Is ActiveX library SNTPWizard free or do we need to buy license? I am not able to find the SNTPWizard licensing site(third party sites are offering for free)... but i need to run this on company device..

Comment: The third party site I found by googling "SNTPWizard", http://sntp-wizard-activex.soft112.com/ , offers a free trial, but the purchase price is $199.  So,  I'd say yes, you need to buy a license.

Comment: only the developer (you) who has to worry about license, not the company you are developing for. that means the license is needed on compile  time only. once compiled the key is integrated with the binary, and you can distribute your software to as many companies you want without worrying about the license.